# Meteor - ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp/meteor/bootstrapping) but midway through step 1 have run into an error. Despite following the tutorial exactly I'm getting the following errors:

```
W20160229-17:37:07.465(0)? (STDERR)
W20160229-17:37:07.465(0)? (STDERR) C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
W20160229-17:37:07.465(0)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20160229-17:37:07.465(0)? (STDERR)                                                   ^
W20160229-17:37:07.465(0)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: angular is not defined
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

The only way I veered from the tutorial is that I am not using the ios or android packages, because I'm on Windows. Could that be the cause?

Either way how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by your app.js file being in the wrong directory. The tutorial sets you up with a file structure like this:

- Client

  - scripts
  - styles
  - templates
  - index.html
- lib
- public
- server

If you put your app.js inside the root "lib" folder you'll get the "angular is not defined" error. It needs to be in a separate "lib" folder inside the "scripts" directory, like this:

- Client

  - scripts

    - lib

      - app.js

You should be able to run the app after moving it.